# Trying to move the last two links in my nav div to other side of container div

Tags: css, html, navigation, hyperlink

Okay, so I have an issue with getting my 'Facebook' and 'Twitter' links to move to the right side of my navigation bar. I want all of the links that stay on the site on the left side of the bar though.

As it stands now, I can't seem to find where the issue is, and how to solve it.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="dropdown-menu.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<br />
<br />


<div id="navdiv">

<ul id="navigation" class="nav-main">

    <li class="list"><a href="index.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    <ul class="nav-sub">
    <li><a href="logo.html">LOGO DESIGN</a></li>
        <li><a href="clothing.html">CLOTHING DESIGN</a></li>
        <li><a href="photoshop.html">PHOTOSHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="layout.html">LAYOUT</a></li>   
    </ul>
    </li>
    <ul>
   <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dbgraphicdesign" title="Facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
    <li class="social"><a href="https://twitter.com/dbergmandesigns" title="Twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>

</ul>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
#navigation{
    margin:auto;
    width:850px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:rgba(194, 6, 6, 0.6);

}

ul.nav-main,
ul.nav-main li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.nav-main{
    position: relative;
}

ul.nav-main li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
}

ul.nav-main li.hover,
ul.nav-main li:hover{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.9);
}

ul.nav-main li{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height: 45px;
    color: #ededed;
    font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul.nav-main li a{
    display:block;
    padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #ededed;
    font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.nav-main li a:hover{
    color:#ededed;
}

ul.nav-sub{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    padding:5px;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    background:rgba(194, 6, 6, 0.8);
}

ul.nav-sub li{
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    height: 22px;
    float: none;
    width:120px;
    background: none;
}

ul.nav-sub li a{
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
    height: 15px;
    width:165px;
    background: none;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    
}

ul img{
height:25px;
}
```

Really hoping that someone can help me out...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ul.nav-main li.social {float: right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here in the 4th lesson it has been described](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

For your variant, the idea is:

```
    <div class="nav-main">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <div class="social">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

so, the css:

```
    .class nav-main {
        position: relative;
    }

    .class social {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        /* optionally
        top: 0; */
    }
```